Does Quran 21:31 imply that earth doesn’t move because of mountains
When you look at Qur'an 21:31, it says

وَجَعَلْنَا فِى ٱلْأَرْضِ رَوَٰسِىَ أَن تَمِيدَ بِهِمْ وَجَعَلْنَا فِيهَا فِجَاجًۭا سُبُلًۭا لَّعَلَّهُمْ يَهْتَدُونَ

The translation in the Clear Qur'an, by Dr. Mustafa Khattab is:

And We have placed firm mountains upon the earth so it does not shake with them, and made in it broad pathways so they may find their way.

When it says that firm mountains have been placed upon the earth so it does not shake, does that mean the Earth doesn’t shake? Today we know that Earth rotates. We also know the Earth shakes during earthquakes and other natural phenomena. May somebody please explain the meaning of this verse.

The word تَمِيدَ in this verse means vibration. not moving or rotating. another verse says earth has many wests and many easts that can be interpreted as rotating.
